# In "The Social Network", what linux program is Mark using to monitor traffic in near real-time?

Tags: linux, netstat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to watch logs in real time via Terminal?](https://serverfault.com/questions/192409/how-to-watch-logs-in-real-time-via-terminal)

The scene where Mark is monitoring TCP/IP connections to his Facemesh website, and comments "look at all this traffic".  What program was he using?  Netstat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/192409/the-social-network-movie-how-to-watch-logs-in-real-time-via-terminal ? I haven't seen the movie, so I'm not sure if this question and the Apache log question are actually asking about the same thing.

Comment: Disagree with the reason for closing. This is a relevant question to system administration, as he is referencing the movie as inspiration to what he wants to do which is in fact server/sys-administration related. I think it should have been closed more appropriately as a dupe.

Comment: yes, that's right -- the movie was inspiring in that, "hey, i want to do that, too."

Answer (score 1):

netstat -anp | grep :80 | wc -l